# Got Error: "raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to clean {folder} with git") SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when trying to install igraph on linux(mint)

Tags: python, installation, syntax-error, igraph

I am trying to install the igraph, using the command bellow:

`pip install python-igraph`

but an error occurred:

```
Collecting python-igraph
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/96/0c027d017a334d22237ef29263d314724bd0f345e8ff122e4133c85cec91/python-igraph-0.9.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-kEbNVg/python-igraph/setup.py", line 465
        raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to clean {folder} with git")
                                                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kEbNVg/python-igraph/
```

I would appreeeciate any help to solve it.

Regards,
Mahshid

Comment: Seems like a Python version problem, check your virtual environment and python version

Comment: Problem with f-string == you're using <3.6 (fstrings were introduced in 3.6)